# Backslash issue in Java string

Tags: java, string

I have a Java piece of code that write some content (an address) to a user properties file:

```
address_string = "http://"+address.getText()+":"+port.getText();

properties.setProperty("url", address_string);

prop.store(new FileOutputStream("user.properties"), "");
```

When I go check the user.properties however, instead of getting a normal http address I got the following:

```
 http\://localhost\:9000/softwarearchive/
```

where the colon is preceded by a backslash

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: When you read the property in java are the backslashes there?  My guess is the ':' character is a special character in .properties files, so it's automatically escaping them when writing the file.  It should unescape them when reading from the file, so you should be OK.

Answer (score 5):

Property files have a specific structure.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Colons are special meta-characters in a property file.  If you want to store a key/value pair where the value has a colon in it, it should probably be escaped to avoid confusion.  Java's property writing library is doing the escaping for you.

If you use `properties.getProperty()`, do you get the string you expect?  If so, things are ok.

Answer (score 4):

":" is used in a properties file to separate the key from the value.  So any ":" in the text needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

No problem. Use [load(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) to read your properties again. Then get `url` from `Properties` as normal.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [properties javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), it's correct behaviour. It unescapes upon loading anyways, so don't worry about your raw data.